# delect NSTextField

Tags: cocoa

When I use

```
[myNSTextField setStringValue:@"AAA"];
```

to set the text of a NSTextField

the texts always have black background and look likes they have been selected.
Is it possible to display the text with black text color and white background color?

Welcome any comment

Comment: Black-on-white is the default configuration of an NSTextField. Did you change the text and background colors? Please edit your question to include a screenshot of the problem so we can see what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask the text field to `resignFirstResponder`. That will deselect the view.

Comment: That will take focus from the field, but won't deselect the text.